# mysql user-defined variable in query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use a user-defined variable to stand-in for a table name so that I can just use mysql and not require any other languages.

This example is way simplistic - the real script uses the table name a LOT and it'd be easier for end-users to be able to just change the variable rather than search/replace.

```
SET @tablename = 'mytable';
SELECT * FROM @tablename;
```

This won't work, but shows the end result I need.

Comment: For users to beable to perform an action from your database by using table names they define themselves.. You are opening up your schema layout... I would avoid doing this..

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is a data conversion script we have to provide for users, we really don't want to. The table names for the old system entirely depend on what the user entered, and we need to know what they are otherwise our import script won't work. The other software was horribly designed IMO

Comment: This could pose a massive security flaw.. I would recommend a re-make of your application.

Comment: I agree with all the comments here. What if the user picks `information_schema` as the table name? This would expose almost all your database information.

Comment: Ok, people are freaking out over my lack of specifics. This is for converting data for a plugin on multiplayer game servers, not any business-class/production server. It's a script people will *always* run on their own databases only. There's no security flaw unless some bonehead let's anyone login and run this sql. It's NOT in any application but is a standalone, delivered .sql file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use prepared statements:

```
SET @tablename = 'mytable';

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @mytable);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

If your actual query is far more complicated, you could wrap the building of the query in some stored function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION GetQuery(tableName VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE finalQuery VARCHAR(100);
    SET finalQuery = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', tableName);
    -- do something fancier with finalQuery here
    RETURN finalQuery;
END //
DELIMITER ;

SET @query = GetQuery('mytable');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Even better: do everything in a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE QueryTable(tableName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @finalQuery = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', tableName);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @finalQuery;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    SET @finalQuery = NULL;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL QueryTable('mytable');
```